# PowerShell - not recognizing the function

Tags: function, powershell

I'm new with PowerShell and i've got a problem I cant deal with.
I have to make my function analyze a lot of folders in a row, but my programm wont work when I give parameters to my function...

```
Param(
    [string]$fPath
)

analyse $fPath
$importList = get-content -Path C:\Users\lamaison-e\Documents\multimediaList.txt
$multimediaList = $importList.Split(',')




function analyse{

    Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $newPath
    )
    cd $newPath
    $Resultat = "Dans le dossier " + $(get-location) + ", il y a " + $(mmInCurrentDir) + " fichier(s) multimedia pour un total de " + $(multimediaSize) + " et il y a " + $(bInCurrentDir) + " documents de bureautique pour un total de " + $(bureautiqueSize) + ". La derniere modification du dossier concerne le fichier " + $(modifDate)
    $Resultat
}
```

It worked when 'analyse' didnt exist but stopped working just after that. CommandNoFoundException. It may be a stupid mistake but i cant deal with it... Thank you for your time.

Comment: `function` is not a declaration, it is a command, that have to be executed to create/modify function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell scripts like yours will be read, line-by-line by the parser.

At the point in time where `analyze $fpath` is being parsed, the function `analyze` doesn't exist in the current scope, since the function definition is further down the script.

To use an inline function inside the script, move the definition up to a point before you call it:

```
Param(
    [string]$fPath
)

# Define the function
function analyse{

    Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $newPath
    )
    cd $newPath
    $Resultat = "Dans le dossier " + $(get-location) + ", il y a " + $(mmInCurrentDir) + " fichier(s) multimedia pour un total de " + $(multimediaSize) + " et il y a " + $(bInCurrentDir) + " documents de bureautique pour un total de " + $(bureautiqueSize) + ". La derniere modification du dossier concerne le fichier " + $(modifDate)
    $Resultat
}

# Now you can use it
analyse $fPath
$importList = get-content -Path C:\Users\lamaison-e\Documents\multimediaList.txt
$multimediaList = $importList.Split(',')
```